# Missing icons when installing zsh and powerlevel9k on Google compute instance?

Tags: ubuntu, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh, google-compute-engine

I found [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/362409/what-is-zsh-and-why-should-you-use-it-instead-of-bash/) on zsh and thought it looked interesting to have a nicer gui on command prompts so installed it via their instructions.

Following the installation I've got missing icons as shown in the picture below. Anyone have ideas on how this happened? Interested to hear anyone's thoughts.

[image: powerlevel9k]